# How to Correctly interpret SEM results?

Tags: r, regression, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, lavaan

Please don't judge me for asking this question, I am still learning statistics and come from a non-mathematical background...

I created a Conceptual Model using lavaan in R and got the following results:

[image]

In order to analyze the results and interpret which elements are the most important (rank them by significance effect), do I look at bets (estimate) or z-value?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "important"?

Comment: @whuber by important I meant significant. From p-values I can tell that they are all statistically significant under 95% confidence level. As I am doing a path analysis, I would like to rank the different variables based on their significance. And to do so, I used the "estimate" column

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything left to ask, then: if you want to rank variables by their "significance," then you need to sort your table by the p-values, not the coefficient estimates.

Comment: @whuber thank you very much for your valuable help! If I just may ask, could you please tell me what the estimate column refers to then?

Comment: Those are the estimated coefficients in the model.

Comment: Thank you so much!